# AChartEngine: "Auto-scaling" a chart with multiple Y-axes

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm using AChartEngine's TimeSeries to display four separate series of values. The "values" have vastly varying scales - one of them is a fraction (varies between 0 and 1), the other has a range of 0 to 1000.

Now, I want to display all four of them simultaneously. I have been able to do this, but the problem is the line for the fraction is always hugging the X-axis since *the variation between 0 and 1 is indistinguishable when the Y axis is from 0 to 1000*.

One solution I though of was that I'd **convert all the values to a common scale before adding them to the series**. That way, all the four lines are always on the same scale. I can get rid of the Y-axes altogether. Cool.

But this presents another problem: I also allow the user to select individual series to view; and this time, I want to

- Display the individual Y-axis
- Display the un-scaled values.

But, since I added scaled values, the chart has now lost the original values and will only display the scaled value.

So, my question is: Is there a way to scale the values on the Y-axes when multiple series are being charted, and to revert to the un-scaled values when the single series is shown?

Also, how do I hide only the Y-axes while still displaying the X-axis?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the multiple scale charting in AChartEngine. The chart type is CombinedXYChart. You can see an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/CombinedTemperatureChart.java).

Another thread explaining this approach is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341770/achartengine-xymultipleseriesrenderer-parameter).

Comment: I wrote some quick trial code and I could see the advantages of using `CombinedXYChart`. I'm still working out how to use multiple scales though. Plus, I'm seeing how well `TimeChart`s play with `CombinedXYChart` (for example - is the time still properly formatted?). I'll post a follow up comment when I have more concrete results.