# AChartEngine XYMultipleSeriesRenderer parameter?

Tags: android, achartengine

I am trying to create a line graph with six lines, and two Y Axis. All six lines will use the same X-axis, but 3 lines should be graphed with respect to one Y-axis, and the other 3 lines graphed with respect to the other Y-axis.

I have been looking at [`this tutorial`](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/MultipleTemperatureChart.java) but cannot quite figure out whats going on.

Does this line represent creating a chart with 2 lines to be graphed, or a chart with 2 y-axis?

```
XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
```

The [`JavaDocs`](http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/renderer/XYMultipleSeriesRenderer.html#XYMultipleSeriesRenderer%28int%29) do not explain the parameter at all. It simply says `scaleNumber`, which is explained nowhere.

Also, is there anyway to work with `AChartEngine` without using Intents? I currently have everything set up to create the graph and just set a `LinearLayout` to display it. There are other things on the page other than the graph.

Comment: you can use `aChartEngine` without intents. you can make it return a view, ex. `ChartFactory.getLineChartView(..` instead of intent and then simply use `.addview()` to your linearLayout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to create a line graph with six lines, and two Y Axis. All six lines will use >the same X-axis, but 3 lines should be graphed with respect to one Y-axis, and the other 3 >lines graphed with respect to the other Y-axis.
>
> I have been looking at this tutorial but cannot quite figure out whats going on.
>
> Does this line represent creating a chart with 2 lines to be graphed, or a chart with 2 y->axis?
>
> XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(2);
> The JavaDocs do not explain the parameter at all. It simply says scaleNumber, which is >explained nowhere.

In short, yes, scaleNumber refers to the number of Y scales that you have in your chart. When another method call refers to scaleNumber, it is normally to clarify which scale to apply the method to.

> Also, is there anyway to work with AChartEngine without using Intents? I currently have everything set up to create the graph and just set a LinearLayout to display it. There are other things on the page other than the graph.

Again, yes. I use it in my applications like this:

```
GraphicalView graph = ChartFactory.getTimeChartView(myContext, data, renderer, xLabelFormat);
    
LinearLayout myLL = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph_container);
myLL.addView(graph);
```

All of the chart types can be retrieved as either Intents or Views (full list in the Javadoc here: http://www.achartengine.org/content/javadoc/org/achartengine/ChartFactory.html)